# Programmatically to list the groups of the current user in a web form sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

How me in web form to list the groups the current user checkboxes to select one or more groups? What would then set the permission to a document on the basis of chosen groups?

I'm doing it right:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
namespace CustomGroupAssignment.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPUser currentUser = web.CurrentUser;
            SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Test_Doc_Lib"];
           // CheckBoxList1 = new CheckBoxList();
            SPGroupCollection webGroups = currentUser.Groups;
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = webGroups;
            CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ID";
            CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Name";
            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

//Break the role inheritance from List and remove any RoleAssignments
        docLib.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
        while (docLib.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
        {
            docLib.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
        }

        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                // Give permissions to a specific group
                SPGroup group = web.Groups.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
                SPPrincipal principalGroup = group;
                SPRoleAssignment roleassignment_group = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
                SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(principalGroup);

                docLib.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
            }
        }
    }
}

}

Comment: I'm doing it right? With the code on top?

Comment: post another question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the existing groups in your `SPUser` by something like:

```
SPGroupCollection webGroups = currentUser.Groups;
checkboxlist.DataSource = webGroups;
checkboxlist.DataValueField = "ID";
checkboxlist.DataTextField = "Name";
checkboxlist.DataBind();
```

Then for giving permissions to particular document/list item.. Iterate through the selected groups by user and do something like:

```
//Break the role inheritance from List and remove any RoleAssignments
item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
while (item.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)  
{ 
    item.RoleAssignments.Remove(0); 
}

foreach (ListItem li in checkboxlist.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        // Give permissions to a specific group
        SPGroup group = web.Groups.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
        SPPrincipal principalGroup = group;
        SPRoleAssignment roleassignment_group = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = workspace.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(principalGroup);

        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    }
}
```

Comment: If replaced SPGroupCollection webGroups = web.Groups; by SPGroupCollection webGroups = currentUser.Groups; ? For current user.

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: How to create a web part to display all of this? I simply just am teaching c # and shrepoint foundation in 2010 and I still do not know how to create web forms and add own code there. Tell me please: how to do it.

Comment: Open Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate -> New Project -> SharePoint tab -> select Visual Web Part! You will have a user control, put your code logic in Visual Web Part and deploy the solution! You can insert this Visual Web Part on any page containing Web Part Zone to use it...

Comment: Do you have examples? For example, I would be easier to do it.

Comment: I recommend you download [SharePoint 2010 Application Development Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6184)

Comment: And how when you click Save, to take the state of checkboxes and groups and overwrite permissions on a document???

Comment: See the second portion of the answer: "Then for giving permissions to particular document/list item.. Iterate through the selected groups by user"

Comment: How do I specify the document just created? I'm doing a redirect in the event handler for ItemAdded and directed him into the web form:       public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdded(properties);
           properties.Cancel = true;
           properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
           properties.RedirectUrl = "/SitePages/test_aspx.aspx";
       }

Comment: You can send the document List Item Id as Query String to your page... And use `SPList.GetItemById([Query String Value]);`

Comment: But how me to use SPList.GetItemById ([Query String Value]);? I find no examples.